# A two variable $f=f(x, y)$ such that its minimum is achieved on the boundary of this halfplane

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, analysis, maxima-minima

Consider the picture here:

[image]

The function taken into account is $f(x) = e^x$ and also the halfplane $x\ge 0$ is highlighted in blue. The point $(0, 1)$ is a minimum for the function in the halfplane $x\ge 0$. During calc I class, it was said that this condition can be expressed in this case availing of first derivative, i.e. saying that
$$\frac{d}{ds} f(s)\Big|_{s=0}\ge 0. $$

More or less I agree with that condition which means to me, roughly speaking, that the function is increasing on the RHS of the point. However, I am trying to understand how this condition should be redrafted in the case $f$ is a function in several variables (e.g. $f=f(x, y)$) for which the minimum is achieved on the boundary.

Intuitively I think it should be something related to its first partial derivatives, but it sounds a bit weird to me that we need to ask something that
$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} (x, y)\Big|_{s=x_0}\ge 0,\qquad \frac{\partial f}{\partial y} (x, y)\Big|_{s=x_0}\ge 0, $$

where $(x_0, y_0)$ is the point where the minimum is achieved.

Do someone have an idea about the conditions to require in this more challenging case?
I am very intrigued by this more challenging situation.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Lets put it this way, if $f(x,y)$ is continuous and differentiable and it takes on an extreme value (minimum or maximum) in the interior of some region, then it must be that $\frac {\partial f}{\partial x} = \frac {\partial f}{\partial y} = 0$ this is a necessary condition but not a sufficient condition.  So, if $\frac {\partial f}{\partial x} >0$ and  $\frac {\partial f}{\partial y} > 0$ the function cannot take on an extreme value in the interior of the region.  If the region is compact, e.g. a closed interval it must take on an extreme value and that value must therefore be on the boundary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $f: \Bbb R^2 \to \Bbb R$ is differentiable and attains its minimum on the right halfplane at some point $(0, y_0)$:
$$
 f(0, y_0) = \min \{ f(x, y) \mid x \ge 0, y \in \Bbb R\}
$$
then

- $x \mapsto g(x) :=  f(x, y_0)$ satisfies $g(x) \ge g(0)$ for $x \ge 0$, so that
  $$
   g'(0) = \frac{\partial f}{\partial x} (x, y)\Big|_{(0, y_0)} \ge 0
  $$
  as you observed for the one-dimensional case, and
- $y \mapsto h(y) :=  f(0, y)$ satisfies $h(y) \ge h(y_0)$ for all $y \in \Bbb R$, so that
  $$
   h'(y_0) = \frac{\partial f}{\partial x} (x, y)\Big|_{(0, y_0)} = 0 
  $$
  because $h$ has a minimum at $y = y_0$.

As in the one-dimensional case, this conditions are necessary, but not sufficient for a minimum on the boundary.

Comment: Martin R, thank you very much for your answer. Could you please add briefly a comment or update the answer about what happens in the 3 dimensional case? in that case the condition is e.g. on the halpspace $xy\ge 0, z\in\mathbb{R}$? Is that true that the mixed partial derivatives play no role? Thank you in advance.

Comment: I am interested in iterating the process in higher dimension, too. If you do not want to answer, please let me know so I can post a new question. Thank you again.

Comment: For higher-dimensional halfspaces it is the same, e.g. if the minimum on $\{ (x, y, z) \mid z \ge 0 \} $ is attained at the boundary, then $f_x = f_y = 0$ and $f_z \ge 0$ at the minimum. For other domains it becomes more complicated. Roughly said, the directional derivatives should be zero for directions which are tangential to the boundary, and $\ge 0$ for for the normal vector pointing to the interior of the domain.

Comment: Martin R, thank you again for your comment. Do you mean also that the mixed partial derivatives $f_{xy}$ play no role? Thank you.

Comment: Also, if you have the minimum on $\{(x, y, z) : xy\ge 0\}$, how does the condition change? Again, if you think it appropriate I post a new question.

Comment: I suggest that you start a new question.